# reuse Visual Foxpro Report in Asp.net

Tags: migration, visual-foxpro

I'm .net developer and have no experience with Visual Foxpro. I have to migrate old system use Visual Fox upto Asp.Net. The old system already use SQL Server to store data, but there are many reports must be migrated, if i can connect to the processed report data. It's seem to be save lot of my effort.
Pls, give me a suggest for this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.vfpconversion.com/Vfp2NetReports.aspx#4

they have a tool that converts foxpro reports to ssrs or crystal reports

Answer (score 0):

There's no magic bullet I'm afraid. You will have to re-do them using, for example, SQL Server Reporting Services.